# Оптимизация кода на пайтоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

я новичок в пайтон и начал его изучать по книге Зеда Шоу, там есть упражнение, выучить вот эту таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил подойти к заданию "творчески" и создать програму-тест типа она пишет вопрос а я отвечаю, получилось очень большой код, при том даже не закончен, и так вопрос знатокам как можно уменшить код не используя сторонних библиотек? Вот код:`

```
from random import randint

def vopros (ask):
    if (ask == 1):
        vopros_1 = input ("Чему равно Not True?\n>")
        if vopros_1 == "False":
            print("Все правильно")
        if vopros_1 == "True":
            print ("Вы ошиблись")
    if (ask == 2):  
        vopros_1 = input ("Чему равно Not False?\n>")
        if vopros_1 == "True":
            print("Все правильно")
        if vopros_1 == "False":
            print ("Вы ошиблись")       

def asking (ask1, zminna, zminna1, zminna2, zminna3 ):
#for or
    if zminna == "True or False":
        if (ask1 == 1):
            vopros_1 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna}?\n> " )
            if vopros_1 == "True":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_1 == "False":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 2):
            vopros_2 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna1}?\n> " )
            if vopros_2 == "True":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_2 == "False":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 3):
            vopros_3 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna2}?\n> " )
            if vopros_3 == "True":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_3 == "False":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 4):
            vopros_4 = input(f"Чему равно {zminna3}?\n> " )
            if vopros_4 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_4 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
#for and 
    if zminna == "True and False":
        if (ask1 == 1):
            vopros_5 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna}?\n> " )
            if vopros_5 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_5 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 2):
            vopros_6 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna1}?\n> " )
            if vopros_6 == "True":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_6 == "False":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 3):
            vopros_7 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna2}?\n> " )
            if vopros_7 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_7 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 4):
            vopros_8 = input(f"Чему равно {zminna3}?\n> " )
            if vopros_8 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_8 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
#for Not or 
    if zminna == "not  (True or False)":
        if (ask1 == 1):
            vopros_9 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna}?\n> " )
            if vopros_9 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_9 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 2):
            vopros_10 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna1}?\n> " )
            if vopros_10 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_10 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 3):
            vopros_11 = input (f"Чему равно {zminna2}?\n> " )
            if vopros_11 == "False":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_11 == "True":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")
        if (ask1 == 4):
            vopros_12 = input(f"Чему равно {zminna3}?\n> " )
            if vopros_12 == "True":
                print("Все Вірно!")
            if vopros_12 == "False":
                print("О ні! Ви помилиись")     

rand = (randint(1,2))
voprosik = vopros(rand)

rand1 = (randint(1,4))
orist = asking(rand1, "True or False", "True or True", "False or True", "False or False")

rand2 = (randint(1,4))
andist = asking(rand2, "True and False", "True and True", "False and True", "False and False")  

rand3 = (randint(1,4))
notorist = asking(rand3, "not (True or False)", "not (True or True)", "not (False or True)", "not (False or False")     
`
```

p.s там есть украинский с русским, не обращайте внимания

Comment: Можно сделать массив объектов вопрос-ответ и тогда случайным образом можно будет выбирать индекс, доставать объект из массива по сгенерированному индексу. Ну и выводить вопрос, проверяя ответ.

Comment: Зачем её учить, её нужно просто понять...

Comment: Учите английский и не называйте переменны транскрипцией. Давайте поиграем. Guitar - что это? Уверен, что никогда не догадаетесь. ////// Когда-то я был шокирован, что в python'е возможно давать названия переменным на кириллице. Хоть я и не признаю такой способ, но, если вам совсем уж никак английский не дается, то, пожалуйста.

Comment: упросить код можно очень просто - написать программу так, чтобы она сама определяла верный ответ. Вы же не будете для проверки знаний таблицы умножения вручную прописывать все варианты от 2х2 до 9х9. Ну, по крайней мере, я надеюсь, что не будете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы самому прописывать все ответы, можно сказать программе самой посчитать правильные ответы. Остаётся лишь определить набор операций и допустимые значения:

```py
import random

UNARY = ('not',)  # Кортеж унарных операторов
BINARY = ('and', 'or')  # Кортеж бинарных операторов

# Кортеж композиции унарных с бинарными
COMPOSITION = tuple((unary, binary) for unary in UNARY for binary in BINARY)

# Получение случайного значения
def get_operand():  
    return random.choice((True, False))

# Получение ответа от пользователя
def get_answer():
    while True:
        answer = input('Твой ответ? ')
        if answer.lower() == 'true':
            return True
        elif answer.lower() == 'false':
            return False
        else:
            print('True/false')

# Проверка ответа и вывод о правильности/неправильности
def check_answer(expected, actual):
    if expected == actual:
        print('Правильно')
    else:
        print('Неправильно')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for operator in UNARY:  # Проверяем для унарных операторов
        operand = get_operand()  # Выбираем случайное значение
        task = f'{operator} {operand}'  # Формируем строку выражения
        print(task)  # Выводим выражение
        your_answer = get_answer()  # Получаем ответ пользователя
        correct_answer = eval(task)  # Говорим программе посчитать ответ
        check_answer(correct_answer, your_answer)  # Сравниваем ответ пользователя с правильным

    for operator in BINARY:  # То же самое для бинарных операторов
        lhs = get_operand()
        rhs = get_operand()
        task = f'{lhs} {operator} {rhs}'
        print(task)
        your_answer = get_answer()
        correct_answer = eval(task)
        check_answer(correct_answer, your_answer)

    for unary_operator, binary_operator in COMPOSITION:  # И для композиций
        lhs = get_operand()
        rhs = get_operand()
        task = f'{unary_operator} ({lhs} {binary_operator} {rhs})'
        print(task)
        your_answer = get_answer()
        correct_answer = eval(task)
        check_answer(correct_answer, your_answer)
```

Каждый запуск будет проверка одних и тех же операторов для псевдослучайных значений.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```py
from radom import randint
# список вопрос-ответ
q_and_a= [
    ('Чему равно not False ?', 'True'),
    ('Чему равно not True ?', 'False'),
]
q_m = len(q_and_a)
c = randint(q_m) # количество вопросов
for _ in range():
    qeu = q_and_a[randint(q_m)] # выбирает рандомный вопрос
    print('Верно.' if input(qeu[0])==qeu[1] else 'Учи дальше.') # проверяем ответ и выводим результат
```

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу в питоне не силен, но захотел сделать :)

Вот пример как можно сделать:

```
from random import randint

questions = [
    ["NOT",[["not False?", "True"], ["not True", "False"]]],
    ["OR", [["True or False?", "True"], ["True or True?", "True"],
            ["False or True?", "True"], ["False or False?", "False"]]]
    ]
    
while(True):
    theme = randint(0,len(questions) - 1)
    print("Тема вопроса:", questions[theme][0])
    question = (randint(0,len(questions[theme][1])) - 1)
    print("Вопрос: ", questions[theme][1][question][0])
    answer = input()
    if answer ==  questions[theme][1][question][1]:
        print("Правильно!")
    else: 
        print("Не правильно!")
```

То есть в массив `questions` можно добавлять тему вопроса, первый элемент будет название темы, второй элемент это массив вопросов.

Сам массив вопросов это по факту массив массивов, где 1 элемент сам вопрос, а 2 это правильный ответ на вопрос. Я думаю когда вы дойдете до ООП можете вернуться к этой задаче и упростить массив вопросов.

P.S. просто как идея вы можете перетасовать массив `questions` потом через цикл вопросы у всех тем. Добавить переменную отвечающую за кол-во всего вопросов и счетчик правильных ответов. И тогда можно будет сделать программу, на проверку знаний с подсчетом правильных ответов.